# UPDATE statement algorithm

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have two tables.

Table 1:

```
ID NAME
1  'AAA'
2  'BBB'
```

Table 2:

```
ID IDNAME
1  'CCC'
1  'DDD'
```

I have to update first table values so I am using below query:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.name = b.IDname 
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.id
```

Now, my question is how SQL Server updates the value from `table 2` as there are two rows for `ID = 1` in `table 2`.

I need explanation and any algorithm used by SQL Server while updating values from multiple rows.

Comment: You probably rather need a specific output than an explanation. What is it?

Answer (score 3):

If you update the same row multiple times it is undefined which ones of the writes actually happens. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is typical example of `Non deterministic update`. A statement is non deterministic when multiple source rows match one target row. Unfortunately in such a case SQL server neither throws an error nor generate a warning. SQL server silently performs a non deterministic update where one of the source rows arbitrarily `wins`.
Instead of using `Non deterministic update` based on joins you should use `Merge` statement.
The latter generates an error when multiple source rows match one target row making the overall condition `deterministic`.

Comment: "A statement is non deterministic when multiple source rows match one target row"... a statement can be non deterministic in other cases, i.e. `SELECT GETDATE()` is also non deterministic

Comment: Yes that's true .. above i meant in this specific scenario- update based on joins. `Nondeterministic functions` may return different results each time they are called with a specific set of input values.

Comment: hmmm your answer looks like something straight out of training kit 70-461 and your comment looks like something from technet, perhaps you should attribute in future.

Comment: I understand that .. will take care in future!!

Answer (score 0):

> ## [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms177523(v=sql.110).aspx)
>
> ...
>
> The results of an `UPDATE` statement are undefined if the statement includes a `FROM` clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the `UPDATE` statement is not deterministic. For example, in the `UPDATE` statement in the following script, both rows in `Table1` meet the qualifications of the `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE` statement; but it is undefined which row from Table1 is used to update the row in `Table2`.